# VisualStudio - aliases for very long watch variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug a tree-like structure, so i have made a watch on each level. The lower i go, the watch variable name is getting ridiculusly long. Is there a way to rename them from:

```
{,,HTM_Projekt.exe}*(Node*){*}(((*((*(((*((*this).htm)).top)._Myptr)).input)))._Myptr)
```

to

```
Level1Node
```

Comment: +1 for you dogged determination in writing so many nested levels out by hand. why not declare a variable on each level?

Comment: i do not want to add unnecesary code, in this case some globals, just to have the names shorter.

Comment: Just help and write your code to be debuggable.  Like storing the node pointer in a local variable while you traverse the tree, something like that anyway.  It doesn't cost anything at runtime that you would ever notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without more details on how you have it structured. i would suggest you make a varriable of that type that equals what is in your tree and just put that varriable on watch. it just means you will have a little bit of duplicate data but can see what it is clearly.

maybe it would look something like.

```
Node* kpLevel1Node = (Node*){*}(((*((*(((*((*this).htm)).top)._Myptr)).input)))._Myptr);
```

and then you just add kpLevel1Node to watch.

EDIT 1:
based off comment.

a pointer is only 4bytes and refrences the same data. but if the extra 4 bytes is not an option for you temporarily while you debug.

then i suggest you use typedef's. to make the long rediculas type into something more readable. and like before without more code showing your implementation an exsact answer is not really possible

Comment: this is what i wish to avoid

Comment: then i suggest you make use of typdef's that way the typedef'd name will be what displays in your watchlist.

Comment: i guess that will have to do for now, they should introduce this soon, though

Comment: well its not overly requried. and the next update to c++ is in 2017. so if something like that comes out. it wont be for a while.

Comment: I agree, I wish visual studio could let your rename your expression so it would read "level_1_node" in the watch table, but when I click it it turns back into the expression.